# Customize HTML for field in field collection

Tags: 7, theming, entities

My field collection template is ds-1col--field-collection-item-field-video-item.tpl.php. I need to access the Image field so that I can customize the HTML. I've tried the following by neither work:

```
<?php print $fields['field_video_image'][0]['und']['value']; ?>
```

and

```
<?php print $fields['field_video_image']->content; ?>
```

I also need to wrap each field collection item in its own div. For instance, each image should be wrapped in a videoClip div but right now all field items are rendering inside videoClip. Also I need to get the delta value of each field item to add it to as part of a CSS class. How can I do this?

Current fields wrapped in custom HTML together:

```
<div class="ds-1col entity entity-field-collection-item field-collection-item-field-video-item view-mode-full clearfix">
<div class="videoClip">
    <div class="videoImg">
        <div class="featuredVideo"></div>
        <div class="field field-name-field-video-image field-type-image field-label-hidden">
            <div class="field-items">
                <div class="field-item even"><!-- image here --></div>
                <div class="field-item odd"><!-- image here --></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="field field-name-field-video-caption field-type-text field-label-hidden">
    <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item even"><!-- video caption --></div>
        <div class="field-item odd"><!-- video caption --> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If your template is being recognized you can access the fields and field content through the `$content` array. Below is the normal field collection item template file that comes with the field_collection module.

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation for field collection items.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - $content: An array of comment items. Use render($content) to print them all, or
 *   print a subset such as render($content['field_example']). Use
 *   hide($content['field_example']) to temporarily suppress the printing of a
 *   given element.
 * - $title: The (sanitized) field collection item label.
 * - $url: Direct url of the current entity if specified.
 * - $page: Flag for the full page state.
 * - $classes: String of classes that can be used to style contextually through
 *   CSS. It can be manipulated through the variable $classes_array from
 *   preprocess functions. By default the following classes are available, where
 *   the parts enclosed by {} are replaced by the appropriate values:
 *   - entity-field-collection-item
 *   - field-collection-item-{field_name}
 *
 * Other variables:
 * - $classes_array: Array of html class attribute values. It is flattened
 *   into a string within the variable $classes.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess()
 * @see template_preprocess_entity()
 * @see template_process()
 */
?>
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <div class="content"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php
      print render($content);
    ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) you can use `dpm($content);` and you will see the below setup.

[image: $content array using devel]

So as you see in field collection item you could use `$content['field_field_1'][0]['#markup']` if your field has extra markup (like for instance if it was set to display as a link to from entity_reference). You could use `$content['field_field_1']['#items'][0]['safe_value']` to get the safe value of the field (sanitized). If you want to customize the markup around a certain field you can hide the field and the render it somewhere else. See the below code for an example.

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation for field collection items.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - $content: An array of comment items. Use render($content) to print them all, or
 *   print a subset such as render($content['field_example']). Use
 *   hide($content['field_example']) to temporarily suppress the printing of a
 *   given element.
 * - $title: The (sanitized) field collection item label.
 * - $url: Direct url of the current entity if specified.
 * - $page: Flag for the full page state.
 * - $classes: String of classes that can be used to style contextually through
 *   CSS. It can be manipulated through the variable $classes_array from
 *   preprocess functions. By default the following classes are available, where
 *   the parts enclosed by {} are replaced by the appropriate values:
 *   - entity-field-collection-item
 *   - field-collection-item-{field_name}
 *
 * Other variables:
 * - $classes_array: Array of html class attribute values. It is flattened
 *   into a string within the variable $classes.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess()
 * @see template_preprocess_entity()
 * @see template_process()
 */
?>
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <div class="content"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php
      // Hide field collection field.
      hide($content['field_image']);
      print render($content);
    ?>
  </div>
</div>
<section class="row">
  <div class=" large-4 columns">
    <!-- Render field_image field collection field-->
    <?php print render($content['field_image']); ?>
  </div>
</section>
```

Hopefully all of this helps, if not let me know and I can adjust to what exactly you are needing or explain more :)

Comment: Thanks for this. It does print the fields but I ned each image field to be wrapped in custom HTML. Right now the image fields are all wrapped together in my custom HTML. I've edited my original question with more details

Comment: You need to look at the second part of my code, I placed that field image from a field collection inside custom divs there so that's essentially what you are looking for, please explain the differences if you can. And you can print out anything else you need by using devel to see what is in the render array by this time.

Comment: In my original question, the field items are all printing inside videoClip wrapper. I need each individual field item to print in its own videoClip wrapper. The template I entered your code in is ds-1col--field-collection-item-field-video-item.tpl.php

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there a way I can access the field from field collection inside a Views template? The Views includes the field collection, I just need to access  one of the fields from this field collection

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign field collection field in `hook_preprocess_node` as a variable then use this variable in your node template file. Some thing like [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165990/print-specific-field-of-a-specific-node/165991#165991)

Comment: Thanks. Can I do this to use variable in a View template? Also how can I get the delta value if there are multiple field collections in one View?

Comment: use field_collection_views module for Views in field collection